# Compiling boost 1.55.0 library on windows 8

Tags: c++, boost

I have downloaded the boost 1.55.0 library. I have used 1.54.0 before.

To build the library 1.54.0, I followed the steps as stated [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source)

i.e. Run the 'bootstrap.bat' then run the 'b2.exe'. I was able to build 1.54.0 version successfully.

While I tried to follow the same steps with version 1.55.0, I am not able to get b2.exe which is generated after running 'bootstrap.bat'

Can someone please help me on this? OR am I missing any step?

Answer (score 0):

**Boost 1.55.0 with Visual Studio 2012 x64**

1. Download boost 1.55.0 from http://www.boost.org/
2. Extract files (e.g. “C:\thirdparty\vs2012\x64\boost_1_55_0”)
3. Start Visual Studio 2012 x64 command prompt (“Open VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt“)
4. Change to boost directory (e.g. “cd C:\thirdparty\vs2012\x64\boost_1_55_0”)
5. Execute `.\bootstrap.bat`
6. Execute

   ```
   b2 address-model=64 toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage
   ```

   If only certain libraries (for instance filesystem) are need step 6 can be replaced by this:

   ```
   b2 address-model=64 toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage --with-filesystem --with-signals --with-system
   ```

**Boost 1.57.0 with Visual Studio 2013 x64**

1. Download boost 1.55.0 from http://www.boost.org/
2. Extract files (e.g. “C:\thirdparty\vs2013\x64\boost_1_55_0”)
3. Start Visual Studio 2013 x64 command prompt (“VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt “)
4. Change to boost directory (e.g. “cd C:\thirdparty\vs2013\x64\boost_1_55_0”)
5. Execute `.\bootstrap.bat`
6. Execute `b2 --toolset=msvc-12.0 address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage`

Take also a look at [BlueGo](http://vertexwahn.de/bluego.html)